# php and mysql error database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database, and I'm trying to insert data form a form into the database.  After that, I entered invalid data, and gave me the error

```
connection error Cannot add or update a child row: 
  a foreign key constraint fails 
  (`infomags`.`details`, CONSTRAINT `details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
  (`cate_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`))
```

I tried to handle this error, but it can't read the column and gave me this error:

```
(connection error Unknown column 'category_id' in 'field list')
```

Comment: I would ask this on the DBA pages.

Comment: with this much information no body can give you any suggestion? please paste your code by pointing out that line where you think error is coming. Also elaborate your problem correctly in an understandable manner.thanks.

Comment: Especially the **in an understandable manner**

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to insert into the `details` table, but the category ID doesn't exist in the `categories` table.

Comment: can you post your code?